# Difference between 1-way binding and 2-way binding in Vue js?

Tags: vuejs2

Could anyone explain the difference between `One-way binding` and `Two-way binding` in Vue js with an example each, and explain which situation to be used?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`One-way binding` is updating the `DOM` from the data (ViewModel). Always when the data (ViewModel) changes, the associated `node` (element) is re-rendered:

```
<span>Message: {{ msg }}</span>
```

With the `v-once` directive, the whole binding is only done once - even when the data changes.

`Two-way binding` is updating the `DOM` from the data (ViewModel) **and** updating the data (ViewModel) on events from the `node` (element).
Normally input fields are `Two-way binding` to reflect changes from the user back to the data:

```
<input v-model="message" placeholder="edit me">
<p>Message is: {{ message }}</p>
```

Please read the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/).